# Is there a linear transformation without an associated matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

We already know that every matrix has an associated transformation with it and this transformation is always linear (which is easy to prove).
However, I was wondering if this is an iff statement?
Basically, can I have a linear transformation without an associated matrix for the transformation.
If yes, please show me one such transformation.
If no, can you prove it?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  What about a linear transformation on an infinite-dimensional vector space?

Comment: Well, this depends on what you mean by "associated". In the case of finite-dimensional vector spaces, every linear map between them can be described by a matrix upon introducing coordinates; in fact, we have an isomorphism $\mathrm{Hom}_K(V,W)\rightarrow K^{n\times m}$ for $V,W$ finite-dimensional $K$-vector spaces of dimensions $m,n$ respectively.

Comment: I think the trivial linear map between two zero dimensional vector spaces cannot be represented by a matrix, since the basis is the empty set.

Comment: Let $T:C[0,1]\to C[0,1]$ be defined by $(Tf)(x) = f(1-x)$.

Comment: @Thorgott By "associated" I meant a matrix when multiplied to a vector has the same image as the one produced by the linear transformation. 
I would also like to point out that I have not yet reached a point where I have dealt with infinite dimensional vector spaces so it would be really helpful if somebody could guide me to the right resources to understand what is being said.

Comment: @ArinChaudhuri This is a question of definition to be fair, but I'd say that map is represented by the empty $0\times0$ matrix. 
@ SannatBhasin You can only multiply a vector in spaces like $K^m$ with a matrix (of the right dimensions) and this will yield a vector in a $K^n$, so you can't directly represent a linear transformation between arbitrary vector spaces $V,W$ like this. However, this does work out after introducing coordinates. This is covered in any standard Linear Algebra text.

Comment: @Thorgott Thank you for your inputs. I am still covering euclidean spaces in my linear algebra class (I will be taking the course that abstracts this to arbitrary vector spaces next semester). So as far as I am concerned, this is my take-away from this post: every linear transformation in a euclidean space will have an associated matrix but when we consider arbitrary vector spaces, it is not necessarily true.

Answer (score 0):

For a linear mapping $\varphi:V\to W$ for two vector spaces $V$ and $W,$ $\varphi$ can always be equivalent to a matrix. Consider the space $V^\ast.$ It's the collection of all linear mappings from the space to its field. For example, the linear mapping $\varphi\!\left(\begin{bmatrix}a \\ b\end{bmatrix}\right)=a+b$ where $+$ is field addition. This corresponds to the co-vector $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}.$ You could, in general, define these linear maps by collapsing over the free vector space, $F\!\left(V\times W^\ast\right)/\sim.$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am not formally introduced to fields yet. Could you help me out by explaining this in easier "linear algebra" terms or guiding me to some resource that might help me understand some statements you made?

Comment: Here are some handy resources to follow:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map
Understanding general linear maps will come in handy for deriving matrices. Another thing to study to understand why linear maps are equivalent to a certain matrix is equivalence classes.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class
The S/~ notation. Then, look at algebraic dual spaces.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space
This is maybe a little beyond first year linear algebra. But if you wanna understand it, I recommend https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dtvM-CzNe50
The whole series is good, actually

Comment: Sorry, ran out of room. But a field is just an algebraic structure that vector spaces are defined over. In essence, it's a set F with multiplication and addition that behaves like the real numbers. I'll take this chance to self advertise as I wrote on this on zackwalker.tk ... there's also wikipedia... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)

Comment: If you follow these resources, you'll figure out that, in fact, we define matrix multiplication directly from the definition of linear maps; that's where it comes from! :)

Comment: If you just want to get right into the mathematical reason why linear maps between two vector spaces can always be a matrix, jump to this section: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map#Matrices

Comment: Thank you so much for all your inputs :)